# Is there a way to disable/remove screenshot soft button or remap it for some other function?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, screenshots, softkey

I have 7" 4.2.2 tablet for everyday use and it have 2 additional soft buttons. Rightmost one is a "screenshot" soft button (please find picture below). My problem is what I rarely take screenshots intentionally (<kbd>Vol- + Power</kbd> is more than enough for me and produces better quality screenshots) but this button and its position causes literally a tons of accidental screenshots. Even worse, this button remains fully functional even when device is locked.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

It there a way to disable this soft button (at least for lock-screen)? Or remove it completely? Or even better, to bind for some more useful function?

FWIW, tablet is Mediatek-based and I have a root.

Comment: Does your device have hardware keys as an alternative for those important soft keys? If yes, then try [Gravitybox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox). It would create its own navigation bar and allows you to choose which keys would you like to show at the bottom. Can't say whether it would work in your case, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Firelord, no, just basic Vol+ Vol- and Pwr.

Comment: Yeah, as @Firelord said, if you have Xposed installed, you could try using a custom navigation bar that's available in GravityBox.. Moreover, if that doesn't help, if you really know how, try editing the SystemUI.apk by decompiling using APKTool